# Facing issue in IntelliJ : Cannot load facet Android (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, error-handling

I came across this error in the recent time. "Cannot load facet Android".
Was Not able to figure out how to resolve this.

I made sure that my android SDK path is correctly updated in the IDE,
It was so that's not the issue.